# Looking for open source video making (from still images) software for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, video-editing

I want to create a small videos in Windows from still images, and trying to find some open source software for the same.

Comment: I don't understand why people are making edit and downgrading the points? Is this English writing forum or what? Please try to stick to requirement rather than CLEAN English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FFMPeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is the Swiss Army Knife of the Video world and it is free, open source & cross platform *including Windows*.

If you are not afraid of the command like then you can do what you need quite handily.

e.g.: `ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -start_number 126 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

I would also suggest checking out [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/), which uses ffmpeg under the hood, with several other tools, and allows things like creating a video clip from a single of image as simple as:

```
myclip = ImageClip("some_picture.jpeg", duration=10)
```

or from a sequence:

```
clip = ImageSequenceClip(['image_file1.jpeg', ...], fps=24)
```

or from text:

```
clip = TextClip("Hello !", font="Amiri-Bold", fontsize=70, color="black")
```

Comment: It seems to be meeting the expectation of making videos but any idea about adding effects to frames or some sort of animation it allows?
Also, is there a UI for the same. Ya. I may sound bit lazy but thought to check if you are aware of any.

Comment: There are several GUIs for ffmpeg _but not all of them expose all of the controls_, for fade in/out see http://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_fade_in_fade_out_transitions_effects_filters.php but you can do almost anything by generating intermediate images with tools like gimp, imagemagick, etc. Take a look at Avanti, AutoMKV. & WinFF.

Comment: @tbp_09 - I have added some information about a pythonic way of using ffmpeg that you may like.